# class file in JAR seems to be ignored; class file being picked up from directory on classpath instead

Tags: java, jar, classpath, archive

I am trying to get a simple JAR file executing on the CLI (without a manifest). The folder structure is as follows:

```
mods\un.jar
out\test\Main.class
src\test\Main.java
```

Here is `Main.java`:

```
package test;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Unnamed module...");

  }
}
```

Here are the commands from the root folder:

```
javac -d out src\Main.java
java -cp out test.Main      - this works
jar -cvf mods\un.jar out\test\Main.class
java -cp mods\un.jar;out test.Main   - works (when 'out' is in classpath)
java -cp mods\un.jar test.Main - ERROR
```

The last line generates the errors:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class test.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Main
```

I have looked at the JAR zip and it looks ok. The MANIFEST.MF is the default one but that is okay as I am explicitly telling Java what class to start with (the class with main()). The contents are:

```
META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
out\test\Main.class
```

The manifest itself is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 11 (Oracle Corporation)
```

So it looks like the class file in the JAR is not being picked up at all. If I omit the `out` folder when I run `java` or if I rename the `.class` file in the `out` folder), I get the class not found error. I would like to get it working without a manifest.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Seán.

Comment: *out\test\Main.class* Yes that's wrong. Should be `test\Main.class` and `jar -cvf mods\un.jar -C out test\Main.class`

Comment: You have additional folder `out` in your jar, so test.Main is not found.

Comment: That worked great @g00se, thanks! I have seen "-C ." quite a bit as well - what does the " ." mean in that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change to the 'out' directory to get your package root correct in the jar:

```
jar -cvf mods\un.jar -C out test\Main.class
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a mill for the prompt response and especially for including the actual correct command.